# How do i test my minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a minecraft server but no minecraft account. How do i test the server world. (i.e. login to world just to test)

Comment: How do you have a server without an account?

Comment: That's easy, just download the jar and execute it. But WHY do you have a server, but no account?

Comment: Even those we are not supposed to ask authors intent, I am also curious why you would create a Minecraft server if you don't have an account.  You could run the server, stop it, move the world files to the saves folder and play the world in single player demo mode.  That is the only legal option I can think of.  It still doesn't test the operation of your server though.

Comment: @IronAnvil That's fine. I am creating it for my friend.

Comment: surely the best way is to actually log into it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Minecraft Server Status Checker](https://mcsrvstat.us/). (3rd party)
With this tool you are at least able to see if the server is online, how many players are allowed and what the message of the day is.

The only way to know for sure if the world loads correctly would either be to actually log in to the server, or to use [@IronAnvil](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/186522/ironanvil) 's suggested idea.

> *You could run the server, stop it, move the world files to the saves folder and play the world in single player demo mode. That is the only
> legal option I can think of. It still doesn't test the operation of
> your server though.*

This answer originally linked to [DinnerBone's website](https://dinnerbone.com/minecraft/tools/status/) which did not function anymore.

Comment: I used the python version: https://github.com/Dinnerbone/mcstatus

Comment: Dinnerbone's server status checker stopped working at some point, possibly as far back as October 2018. I've reported the problem, but so far had no response.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you ask your friend to log in to your server who has an account? Surely he must have an account.

Answer (score 1):

You can, in the server properties, turn the server into offline mode by simply changing:

```
online-mode=false
```